# Getting ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length while reshaping tensor for Bidirectional LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, bidirectional

y_pred length returns 13, y_test length returns 13 as well however y_pred.reshape(-1) returns 130. y_pred argument expects one argument, how do I reshape it back to 13?

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,Activation, LSTM,Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf

BLSTM = Sequential()
BLSTM.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(10,1), activation='gelu')))
BLSTM.add(Dense(1))
BLSTM.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
BLSTM.build(input_shape=(10,1,1))
BLSTM.summary()
history = BLSTM.fit(X_train_t, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128)
BLSTM.evaluate(X_test_t, y_test, batch_size=32)
y_pred = BLSTM.predict(X_test_t, batch_size=32)
como = pd.DataFrame({'testdata' : y_test.Price.values,'predictions' : example})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your model's summary and the parameters of your `LSTM` layer. You are using an input shape of `(10,1)` meaning you have 10 timesteps and for each timestep you have 1 feature. At least that is what you are telling this layer. Note that this has nothing to do with number of samples you have in your dataset. The full shape would be `(samples, timesteps, features)`. And then you have set the `return_sequences` parameter to `True`, which means you will get all timesteps from your input resulting in the output shape `(None, 10, 200)`, where 200 is the output space is due to the `Bidirectional` layer and `None` is some variable batch size.

Now based on this information, you have to ask yourself if your data does really have the shape `(samples, 10, 1)`, because if this is the case, you are building your model with the wrong shape: `input_shape=(10,1)` != `input_shape=(10,1,1)`. The timesteps dimension is different and that is probably causing the issues with your model. Here is one example of what your model would look like if `x_train` and `y_train` both have the shape `(samples, 10, 1)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

timesteps = 10
features = 1
BLSTM = tf.keras.Sequential()
BLSTM.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, features))))
BLSTM.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
BLSTM.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
BLSTM.build(input_shape=(1, timesteps, features))
BLSTM.summary()

samples = 500
X_train_t = tf.random.normal((samples, timesteps, features))
y_train = tf.random.normal((samples, timesteps, features))

X_test_t = tf.random.normal((samples, timesteps, features))
y_test = tf.random.normal((samples, timesteps, features))

history = BLSTM.fit(X_train_t, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=128)

BLSTM.evaluate(X_test_t, y_test, batch_size=32)
y_pred = BLSTM.predict(X_test_t, batch_size=32)
print(y_pred.shape)
```

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 bidirectional_10 (Bidirecti  (1, 10, 200)             81600     
 onal)                                                           
                                                                 
 dense_10 (Dense)            (1, 10, 1)                201       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 81,801
Trainable params: 81,801
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
4/4 [==============================] - 8s 16ms/step - loss: 0.9933
16/16 [==============================] - 2s 7ms/step - loss: 0.9771
(500, 10, 1)
```

`X_test_t` and `y_test` also have to have the same shape.

Comment: What shape do you have currently and what shape do you need?

Comment: I have 3d array with 13 columns in y_pred as (13,10,1) turned into
130 columns so I need to reduce it back to 13.  I have tried this: pd.DataFrame({'test' : y_test.Price.values,'pred': y_pred.reshape(-1)}). In my case y_test.Price.values being "price" I am trying to predict.

Comment: I can see it working however pd.DataFrame({'test' : y_test.Price.values,'pred': y_pred}) barks an error saying "ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional". Does this mean I need to add something at the end of y_pred?

Comment: I have tried y_test.flatten() as well but it keeps saying Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: It does, thank you! Another one that worked was .squeeze()